# Visual Studio intellisense over WebDav (DAVWWW) does not work. Failed to Start Monitoring 

Tags: 2007, development, visual-studio, asp.net, webdav

The page lives in a library inside SharePoint 2007 and has inline c#.. no master page or sharepoint references. I can open, edit and save the page via the URL. But getting warnings and **no intellisense**.

Warning  \sitehere.com\DavWWWRoot\sites\x\zzzz.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'same page'

I understand I can't test (F5) from my client .. but just looking to get C# intellisense.

If I install SharePoint 2007 on my client even if not joined to the farm will it help?

If no way.. Any way to get intellisense in SharePoint Designer 2007?